# Efficiently count occurrences of a value in a Cartesian product of a numeric range with itself

Tags: python, optimization

Here is my code. It builds a multiplication table of size n by n numbers. I need to count k in this array. My code works fine. But, slowly. How can I speed it up? No third party libraries. Everything is on a regular Python.

```
n = 30
k = 2
multiply_arrive = []
for string in range(1,int(n)+1):
    for column in range(1,int(n)+1):
          multiply_arrive.append(string*column)
print(multiply_arrive.count(int(k)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a benchmark of the speed gain with a list comprhension:

```
%%timeit
n = 3000
k = 2
multiply_arrive = []
for string in range(1,int(n)+1):
    for column in range(1,int(n)+1):
          multiply_arrive.append(string*column)
c = multiply_arrive.count(int(k))
```

> 1.22 s ± 156 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit
n = 3000
k = 2
c = [string*column for string in range(1,int(n)+1) for column in range(1,int(n)+1)].count(int(k))
```

> 879 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Furthermore, if could install `numba`:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute(n, k):
    return [string*column for string in range(1,int(n)+1) for column in range(1,int(n)+1)].count(int(k))

n = 3000
k = 2
c = compute(n, k)
```

> 234 ms ± 5.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Or you can avoid creating a list and simply counting the occurrences of your value:

```
%%timeit
n = 3000
k = 9000

counter = 0
for s in range(1, n + 1):
    
    if s > k:
        break
    
    for c in range(1, n + 1):
        
        if c > k:
            break
            
        if s * c == k:
            counter += 1
```

> 692 ms ± 23.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

This is faster, and you can avoid a lot of computations by skipping when one of the factors is already bigger than the number you want to count.

So for example if the number is low:

```
...
k = 100
...
```

> 714 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Then it takes much less. No memory is allocated here.

Also, the multiplication table is symmetric, so you don't need to compute it all, you can compute just half of it and then double the counter value (excluding the values on the diagonal of the table which you would count only if your number is a square):

```
%%timeit

from math import sqrt
n = 3000
k = 100

counter = 0
for s in range(1, n + 1):
    
    if s > k:
        break
    
    for c in range(1, s + 1):
        
        if c > k:
            break
            
        if s * c == k:
            counter += 1

counter = counter * 2
if sqrt(k) % 1 == 0:  # check if number is a square
    counter -= 1  # squares are counted twice
```

> 372 µs ± 6.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Which takes half the time compared to the full computation.

Answer (score 1):

If memory consumption or execution speed is the issue, you could make this as a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#id14).

```
n = 30
k = 2
gen = (i*j for i in range(1, n+1) for j in range(1, n+1))
print(sum(1 for i in gen if i == k)) # Counts k in the generator.
#print(*gen) # Prints the multiplication table from the generator.
```